# Display data from a database in a HTML page using django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to add data to a html page using python but the page is blank apart from the normal elements on the page.

this is my `views.py` :

```
def index(request):
next = request.GET.get('next', '/admin')
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            data = Students.objects.all()
            return render_to_response("login/profile.html", {'data', data})
        else:
            HttpResponse("Inactive User.")
    else:
        print("User Not Found!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

return render(request, 'login/home', {'redirect_to':next})
```

this is my student module :

```
class Students(models.Model):
    student_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=144, blank=True, null=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    gpa = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    course_code = models.ForeignKey(Courses, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='course_code', blank=True, null=True)
    college = models.ForeignKey(Colleges, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    passwords = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'students'
```

my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HEY!!!!</h1>
    <p>
        {{ data.f_name}}
        {{ data.l_name }}
        {{ data.student_number }}
        {{ data.dob }}
    </p>
     <a href="/">logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been looking this up for a while but I can't seem to find why this isn't displaying anything on my page. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me a while but I think that I have finally found an answer for my question.

adding this in to the views.py

```
data = Students.objects.all()

stu = {
    "student_number": data
}


return render_to_response("login/profile.html", stu)
```

then it iterate through the data that is stored in the `stu` variable

```
{% for student in student_number %}
    {{ student.f_name}}
    {{ student.l_name }}
    {{ student.student_number }}
    {{ student.dob }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: doing exactly same thing and getting results from db but whne i do page refresh data do not populates form db

Answer (score 2):

In your context, you pass Student.objects.all() which is a list of students. And then treat is as a single object in the template. You need to iterate over your list.

Comment: I have added this `{% for ---- in ---- %}` but I'm not sure what I should put in in place of the hyphens?

Comment: Look at the examples in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: `{% for student in data %}`

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm still only getting a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that when your `request.method` is not `POST`(should be `GET`), you were not passing `data` in the context. You returned:

```
return render(request, 'login/home', {'redirect_to':next})
```

instead. Django template won't give you error when you have undefined variable, but it won't show anything either.